# C# Wrapper Function Delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following pattern throughout my application, creating a Server object using impersonation to retrieve data.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    Index model = new Index(); 

    using (new Impersonation("domain", "username", "password")){
            Server server = new Server("serverInstance"); 

            model.ApplicationList = server.GetApplications();
            model.Details = server.GetDetails(); 
    }
}
```

I was wondering if this can be translated into a wrapper function. So it can be called the following way

```
SecureManager.PerformOperation("domain", "username", "password", server => server 
{
    server.GetApplications();
    server.GetDetails();
    ....
});
```

The goal is to only use the Server object within the Impersonation block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

```
void /*SecureManager.*/PerformOperation(
   string domain, string username, string password, Action<Server> action)
{
   using (new Impersonation(domain, username, password))
   {
            action(new Server("serverInstance")); 
   }
}
```

But it would not really solve "only use the Server object within the Impersonation block" because that object can be easily "leaked" out of the lambda:

```
  Server leakedServer = null;
  SecureManager.PerformOperation("domain", "username", "password", 
      server => 
      {
         leakedServer = server;  
         ....
       });
  leakedServer.GetApplications();
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the syntax on how to do it? I'm fine with it as long as it gets instantiated in the PerformOperation method, under Impersonation block @Alexei Levenkov